# Unable to install curb gem

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, curl, rubygems, ubuntu-12.10

It gives me the error of

```
 gem install curb
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing curb:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/curb-0.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/curb-0.8.3/ext/gem_make.out
```

**rvm list**

```
rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.3-p385 [ broken ]
=* ruby-1.9.3-p392 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default


user1@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4-openssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libcurl3-gnutls is already the newest version.
libcurl4-openssl-dev is already the newest version.
libcurl3 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

As I remember it uses curl libs to compile natively

So you will need curl dev libs installed
try installing

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

Comment: The first command was ok. The second one gave me `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev  
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcurl4-gnutls-dev : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (= 7.27.0-1ubuntu1) but 7.27.0-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
`

Comment: I think its safe to ignore it as any one command working is fine it should help install the gem properly

Comment: The first command helped me to resolve the error too. Cheers.

Comment: @KarthikT you sure you are facing the same issue?

Answer (score 7):

On fedora I did `sudo yum install curl-devel`  and then did `gem install curb` and that did the trick for me

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me also, CentOS 6.9 using a single user rvm ruby install.

Answer (score 5):

In *Ubuntu 18.04*, using

```
sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

and then install `curb`

```
gem install curb
```

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 14.04, besides the libcurl packages mentioned by PriteshJ, I also have to install ruby-dev package to make it works:

> sudo apt-get install ruby-dev

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, the dependencies can be satisfied by installing the following packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

On RedHat:

```
$ sudo yum install ruby-devel libcurl-devel openssl-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem on an ubuntu 14.04 docker image with curb 0.9.0 and solved it by installing libgmp-dev (in addition to the suggestions from the curb page already mentioned:  libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4-openssl-dev).